# App pages not reading toggle position correctly to change app theme

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to instruct every page in my app to read the theme requested based on the toggle switch position for Dark Mode in my Settings page but for some reason, it's not working properly. Half the time the light mode is set when I open my app, and the other half the dark mode is set despite the Dark Mode toggle set to on. Does anyone know what has gone wrong in my code and how this can be fixed?

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Set theme for window root.
        if (Window.Current.Content is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
        {
            frameworkElement.RequestedTheme = ?;
        }
    }
}
```

**AppSettings.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class AppSettings : Page
{
    public const ElementTheme DEFAULTTHEME = ElementTheme.Light;
    public const ElementTheme NONDEFAULTHEME = ElementTheme.Dark;

    const string KEY_THEME = "appColourMode";
    static ApplicationDataContainer LOCALSETTINGS = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the current app colour setting from memory (light or dark mode).
    /// </summary>
    public static ElementTheme Theme
    {
        get
        {
            // Never set: default theme
            if (LOCALSETTINGS.Values[KEY_THEME] == null)
            {
                LOCALSETTINGS.Values[KEY_THEME] = (int)DEFAULTTHEME;
                return DEFAULTTHEME;
            }
            // Previously set to default theme
            else if ((int)LOCALSETTINGS.Values[KEY_THEME] == (int)DEFAULTTHEME)
                return DEFAULTTHEME;
            // Previously set to non-default theme
            else
                return NONDEFAULTHEME;
        }
        set
        {
            // Error check
            if (value == ElementTheme.Default)
                throw new System.Exception("Only set the theme to light or dark mode!");
            // Never set
            else if (LOCALSETTINGS.Values[KEY_THEME] == null)
                LOCALSETTINGS.Values[KEY_THEME] = (int)value;
            // No change
            else if ((int)value == (int)LOCALSETTINGS.Values[KEY_THEME])
                return;
            // Change
            else
                LOCALSETTINGS.Values[KEY_THEME] = (int)value;
        }
    }

    public AppSettings()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Set theme for window root
        FrameworkElement root = (FrameworkElement)Window.Current.Content;
        root.RequestedTheme = AppSettings.Theme;
        SetThemeToggle(AppSettings.Theme);
    }

    private void SetThemeToggle(ElementTheme theme)
    {
        if (theme == AppSettings.DEFAULTTHEME)
            TglDarkMode.IsOn = false;
        else
            TglDarkMode.IsOn = true;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage.Current.BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MainPage.Current.BackButton.IsEnabled = true;

        MainPage.mAppBarButtonSettings.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage.mAppBarButtonSettings.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void TglDarkMode_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement window = (FrameworkElement)Window.Current.Content;

        ToggleSwitch toggleSwitch = sender as ToggleSwitch;
        if (toggleSwitch != null)
        {
            if (toggleSwitch.IsOn == true)
            {
                AppSettings.Theme = AppSettings.NONDEFAULTHEME;
                window.RequestedTheme = AppSettings.NONDEFAULTHEME;
            }
            else
            {
                AppSettings.Theme = AppSettings.DEFAULTTHEME;
                window.RequestedTheme = AppSettings.DEFAULTTHEME;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Errors: AppSettings.xaml.cs**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the following answer work?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Are both code blocks supposed to go on the same page? My latest screenshots show errors returned after trying this.

Comment: You could remove line of `OnNavigationFailed`.

Comment: `'AppSettings.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs)': No suitable method found to override`

Comment: please place  OnLaunched  in App.xaml.cs file but not AppSettings class.

Comment: After doing that 2 errors are returned: `The name 'Theme' does not exist in the current context`, `The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item`.

Comment: Fine, for better understanding, I shared the code sample [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/AppTheme), please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> App pages not reading toggle position correctly to change app theme

I'm afraid you have not load the theme setting when app launch. Please add the the following method in your  `AppSettings` and call it in  `OnLaunched` method where in the `App.xaml.cs`

```
public static async Task SetRequestedThemeAsync()
{
    foreach (var view in CoreApplication.Views)
    {
        await view.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            if (Window.Current.Content is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
            {
                frameworkElement.RequestedTheme = Theme;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Invoke above in `OnLaunched` method**

```
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (rootFrame == null)
    {            
        rootFrame = new Frame();

        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

        if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
         
        }

        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }

    if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
    {
        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
           
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        
        Window.Current.Activate();
        await AppSettings.SetRequestedThemeAsync();
    }
}
```